# Proportion Tables in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have the following data in R:

```
gender <- c("Male","Female")

gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))

gender <- as.factor(gender)

disease <- c("Yes","No")

disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))

disease <- as.factor(disease)

status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")

status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))

status  <- as.factor(status )

my_data = data.frame(gender, status, disease)
```

I want to make a table that shows:

- What percent of male immigrants have the disease?
- What percent of male non-immigrants have the disease?
- What percent of female immigrants have the disease?
- What percent of female non-immigrants have the disease?

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
 t1 <- xtabs(disease ~ gender + status, data=my_data)

But I get this error:
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want `my_data %>% count(across(everything())) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% group_by(gender) %>% mutate(across(Female:Male, proportions))`

Comment: @ akrun: I tried this and got the following error: Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.  ..... is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you have an old `dplyr` version?  I used `1.0.9`

Comment: @ Akrun: I just checked, I have : dplyr_1.0.9

Comment: In your example data, there is a typo `disease <- as.factor(gender)` ?

Comment: good catch! thank you for pointing this out! I just changed it

Comment: `my_data %>% count(across(everything()))` works for me.  Maybe you have another package that is masking `count` try `my_data %>% dplyr::count(across(everything()))`

Comment: The same error is still appearing ...

Comment: I think your last comment is now making this work!

Comment: `my_data %>% count(across(everything())) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from =n, values_fill = 0) %>% group_by(gender) %>% mutate(across(No:Yes, proportions)) %>% ungroup` this gives me the proportions

Comment: Is it possible to change these to percentages?

Comment: just multiply by 100 as in the solution posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are more columns and all of them are `factor`s, use `count` from `dplyr` and then get the `proportions`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
my_data %>% 
   dplyr::count(across(everything())) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from =n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
   group_by(gender) %>% 
   mutate(100 *across(No:Yes, proportions)) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  gender status       No   Yes
  <fct>  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Female Citizen    69.4  72.4
2 Female Immigrant  30.6  27.6
3 Male   Citizen    70.4  68.7
4 Male   Immigrant  29.6  31.3
```

---

With `xtabs`, if we convert the column to `integer`, it could work as

```
apply(xtabs(n ~ disease + gender + status, 
  transform(my_data, n = as.integer(disease))), c(1, 2), proportions) * 100
, , gender = Female

           disease
status            No      Yes
  Citizen   69.36724 72.41993
  Immigrant 30.63276 27.58007

, , gender = Male

           disease
status            No      Yes
  Citizen   70.40185 68.68687
  Immigrant 29.59815 31.31313
```

Comment: @ akrun: thank you for your answer! when I try this, I get absolute counts and not percentages. I wonder if I might need to use the "::" symbol again somewhere? thank you for all your help!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 you have to use `dplyr::count` as you may have another package loaded with `count` function that masked `dplyr` count

Comment: As soon as I loaded the "tidyr" package, everything seems to be working now!

Comment: @ akrun: one last question - suppose I want to repeat this analysis with the "status" variable removed. I tried this code:

Comment: my_data[,-2] %>% 
    dplyr::count(across(everything())) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from =n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    mutate(100 *across(No:Yes, proportions)) %>% 
    ungroup

Comment: But now all percentages are 100? is there way to accommodate this? thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 are you removing the `status` column?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Do you want `my_data %>% select(-status) %>% dplyr::count(across(everything())) %>% group_by(gender) %>% mutate(n = proportions(n) * 100) %>% ungroup %>% pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from = n)`

Comment: @antonoyaro8 or may be `my_data[,-2] %>% dplyr::count(across(everything())) %>%  pivot_wider(names_from = disease, values_from =n, values_fill = 0) %>%  mutate(100 *across(No:Yes, proportions)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @ akrun: thank you, this worked! I wonder what the difference is between the way I wrote the code and the way you corrected the code? In both instances, the "status" variable is removed, yet yours works correctly and mine doesnt. This has been very informative and helpful thank you again for everything!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 there is only one row after the pivot_wider for 'gender', thus when you group by 'gender' , as there is only a single row, it gives 100 percent.  In the previous case, gender each had two rows (for each status), thus it was giving the percentage of status for each gender